# Why can't I grab state from one component to another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

- I have two function component (component1) and it's a main component and (component2) which i want to grap state data from it

```
import { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

const TestContext = createContext();

function Component1() {
  const test = useContext(TestContext);
  return (

      <h1>{`${test}`}</h1>
      
  );
}

function Component2() {
      const [test, setTest] = useState("From Component 3");

  return (
    <TestContext.Provider value={test}>
      <Component1 />
    </TestContext.Provider>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Component1 />);
```

In this question:

- I want to use only **useContext Hook** to bring state
- I want **Component1** is the rendered component.

I try a lot but always the result is "**undefined**"

Comment: Only `Component1` is rendered, so there's nothing to grab from another component anyway. There is no provided `TestContext` value. That said, React components don't reach into other React components to access any internals. Did you mean to render `Component2` to the DOM instead? Please [edit] to clarify in better detail what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: If i rendred the "component2" the problem will solved, But i want to render "component1" and this is the point .

Comment: What is the point? Like I said, if all you render is `Component1` then there is no other component or context to access. Sorry, it's not clear at all what you are trying to do here other than not use React correctly.

Comment: Guess we have this two component or more, and "component1" is initially rendered component, and we need to grap states from another component to initial component not the opposite by using the "useContext Hook"

Comment: In React data flows in one direction, DOWN. If there is some state that `Component2` further down the ReactTree that `Component1` needs to access, then the state should reside *at least* as high in the ReactTree as `Component1` and be passed down to descendent components. See [React: Sharing State between Components](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is why it says undefined.

- you rendering the wrong component. Instead of `<Component1/>` you have to render the `<Component2/>`

```
import { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

const TestContext = createContext();

function Component1() {
  const test = useContext(TestContext);
  return (
    <h1>{`${test}`}</h1>
  );
}

function Component2() {
  const [test, setTest] = useState("From Component 3");

  return (
    <TestContext.Provider value={test}>
      <Component1 />
    </TestContext.Provider>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Component2 />);
```

With this change, `Component2` will be the initially rendered component, and it will wrap `Component1` with the `TestContext.Provider`, providing the state value. `Component1` can then access the state value through the `useContext` hook.

Comment: I edited your code by mistake, it was unintentional. I apologize

Comment: Ohh! It's ok @IkramAkbar.